# MySQL match against +(search query) not working but +search +query is

Tags: mysql

I have a textinput field where users can enter a search query which I am performing a match against on in MySQL. The user can enter multiple words or single words however when I use +(search query) I get no results however when I use +search +query I get the desired results.

Works

```
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+new +painting' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Does not work

```
MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+(new painting)' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

First time user of MATCH AGAINST so not sure what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all titles with the string "new painting":

MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+"new painting"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)

For all titles with boths the strings "new" and "painting":

MATCH (title) AGAINST ('+new +painting' in BOOLEAN MODE)

For more options, and different operators, consult the documentation: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thanks. I also thought +(something here) produced the same results as +something +here but nevermind. I modified my query to place a + against every new word.

Comment: I think this may not work unless you configured MySql to do the match against for words with fewer than 4 characters.